# presentModalViewController in UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to use presentModalViewController to show ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.
But the modal controller appears in simple UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait, not upside down. So user have to rotate iPhone to select contact.

Is it possible to present modal view controller in UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have to subclass ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.
In my derived class I override only

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

and return YES only for UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown.

And set

```
picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

before presenting it.